# Does adding a new device to Apple Developer account make it available to every app?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I want to add a new device to my list of devices under "All" in Devices category in Apple Developer website in order to have that person download and install an app of mine for testing.

I did a test run of uploading the .IPA file of a different app to Diawi with the devices as they currently are in my list of devices so without adding this new one, and all three devices showed up in list of provisioned devices. I had not added them specifically to the app ID, it was just an app I created on the fly for testing which was associated with my own developer account.

Now, I am just wondering, if I add the UDID of another tester under "All devices" and then proceed to add it to the distribution profile of my app, if they would then stay in the default list for future apps?

I really don't know how this works - would really appreciate if someone can help me out on this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it is a standard development provisioning profile (and not an enterprise distribution profile), this is how it works.

One of the things inside of the provisioning profile is a list of devices on which apps that apps matching the bundle ID (also specified in the provisioning profile) can run.  So if you have a new device, you need to add it to the apple developer account, then add it to the provisioning profile you are using to build the app, re-download the profile to your Mac, then re-build the app.  The new app will have bundled with it the new list of devices on which the app is authorized to run.  Then give the new app to the person with the new device and it should now work for them.

If you try to run the old app, which has a profile that doesn't list the new device's UDID, the app will not run.  Also, simply adding a new device to the list of devices does not automatically add it to any provisioning profiles.  You must then go and edit the profile to choose to include the new device.  Then, once you've done both of those, you must download the profile and then rebuild the app, now packaged with the new profile that includes the new UDID.

Comment: Awesome, but I had a case where I just created a new app and archived it, without making any changes to the list of devices in my developer account. And that app had provisioned all three devices by default, without my having gone in and added them. It just took from the list under "All". Does that make sense?

Comment: What do you mean by the "app had provisioned all three devices"?

Comment: I created a test app, super basic, archived in Xcode in Ad Hoc mode, and uploaded .ipa to Diawi, without making any changes to the provisioning profile. All three devices I had listed previously under "All devices" were listed under provisioned devices that could download and install the app via the link. I am thinking this is maybe due to the fact that these devices are linked to the developer team and are the main ones I generally use?